# Polynomial - number of pairs of positive integers solving the equation

Tags: polynomials

What is the number of pairs of positive integers x,y that solve the equation?

$x^3 + 6x^2y + 12xy^2 + 8y^3= 2^{30}$

a) 0

b) $2^6$

c)  $2^9-1$

d) $2^{10}+2$

How do you solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$x^3+6x^2y+12xy^2+8y^3=(x+2y)^3$$

Can you solve this from here?

Comment: If you don't spot this immediately you can notice that $x$ is even so write $x=2z$ and $8z^3+24z^2y+24zy^2+8y^2=2^{30}$ and $z^3+3z^2y+3zy^2+y^3=(z+y)^3=2^{27}$

Comment: Nice remark, that could be useful in future problems :D

Comment: Can you tell me how you got to that?

Comment: I knew it looked like (x+something)^3, then i checked $(x+2y)^3$. But Mark Bennet has shown you a more algorithmic way to see it. But you must at least know that $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth pointing out that, in general, you can't solve this kind of problem; given any [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) (such as yours), the problem of finding a set of integers for the unknowns is undecidable: if there is at least one solution, you can theoretically find it by iteratively trying different combinations of integers, but if there is no solution, there is no algorithm capable of determining this. For more information, see [Hilbert's 10th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem).